# Find frequency of occurrence, minmax without storing input

Tags: c, integer, max, min

The task is to read N digits within a range from 0 to 9 and find frequency of occurrence for entered digits. In addition to that, I need to find min and max values and also the most common number(s). Using at least 3 functions is required(storing input isn't allowed))

So far I completed finding occurrences and min and max value entered.
I have problems with finding the most common number(s) and creating functions. I have created separate variables for each number to find the frequency.
Also, this code doesn't seem to be very good and in case you have better solutions for this problem, please share.

```
{
    int n=0;
    int max=0,min=9;
    int freq0=0,freq1=0,freq2=0,freq3=0,freq4=0,freq5=0,freq6=0,freq7=0,freq8=0,freq9=0;

    for (;;)
    {
        printf ("Please enter the number in range from 0 to 9 (to break enter: 11): ");
        scanf ("%d",&n);
        if (n==11)//to exit the loop 11 is setteled as a stop value
            break;
        if (n==0)
            freq0++;
        if (n==1)
            freq1++;
        if (n==2)
            freq2++;
        if (n==3)
            freq3++;
        if (n==4)
            freq4++;
        if (n==5)
            freq5++;
        if (n==6)
            freq6++;
        if (n==7)
            freq7++;
        if (n==8)
            freq8++;
        if (n==9)
            freq9++;
        if (n>max)
            max=n;
        if (n<min)
            min=n;
    }

    printf ("Number 0 occured %d times\n",freq0);
    printf ("Number 1 occured %d times\n",freq1);
    printf ("Number 2 occured %d times\n",freq2);
    printf ("Number 3 occured %d times\n",freq3);
    printf ("Number 4 occured %d times\n",freq4);
    printf ("Number 5 occured %d times\n",freq5);
    printf ("Number 6 occured %d times\n",freq6);
    printf ("Number 7 occured %d times\n",freq7);
    printf ("Number 8 occured %d times\n",freq8);
    printf ("Number 9 occured %d times\n",freq9);
    printf ("highest %d \n", max);
    printf ("smallest %d\n",min);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to use an array here. This will divide the number of lines of your program by aproximately 10. Imagine what your program would look like if you had numbers from 0 to 100 instead of numbers from 0 to 9.

Comment: ... and what's _"the most common number(s)"_? Show an example. [Edit]  your question.

Comment: Always, always, always check `scanf()`'s return value to see if it succeeded. What if someone entered `a` instead of a number, or just did a `^D` to trigger end of file?

Comment: Are you supposed to enter a value for `N` to begin with? Also it says *using* 3 functions. So far you have used 3 functions: `main`, `scanf`, `printf`.

Comment: ... and what's supposed to happen if the user enters e.g. `12`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky The teacher told me that I shouldn't store the numbers to the array, in case if the user decided to enter a million values (for example).
The most common means the highest frequency, for example, if I enter 2 3 4 2< number the is the most common one.

Comment: @Shawn Yes, right, missed that part, thanks

Comment: @WeatherVane no value for N. 
Functions that are required is either void or some type of returning function.
Didn't clarify it properly, my bad

Comment: @Marietta you obviously misunderstood something. The size of the array will be 10 here and the user still will be able to enter one million numbers. The answers below are exactly what you need.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I was solving this exercise using an array and after showing it to my teacher he didn't accept it, but maybe I really misunderstood what he wants.
Anyway, thanks for the help

Comment: @Marietta well then you need to ask your teacher what he wants. We can't guess what he wants. Your program is basically using a poor man's array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

#define MIN(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))

int main(void) {
    int n=0;
    int value_max=INT_MIN;
    int value_min=INT_MAX;
    int freq[10] = {0};

    for(;;)
    {
        printf ("Please enter the number in range from 0 to 9 (to break enter: 11): \n");
        scanf ("%d",&n);
        if (n==11) break;
        freq[n]++;
        value_max = MAX(n, value_max);
        value_min = MIN(n, value_min);
    }

    for(n=0; n<10; ++n)
    {
        if (freq[n] == 0) continue;
        printf("Frequency of %d : %d\n", n, freq[n]);
    }
    printf("Maximum value : %d\n", value_max);
    printf("Minimum value : %d\n", value_min);

    return 0;
}
```

### Test Input

```
4 5 6 1 2 3 4 5 6 11
```

### Output

```
Frequency of 1 : 1
Frequency of 2 : 1
Frequency of 3 : 1
Frequency of 4 : 2
Frequency of 5 : 2
Frequency of 6 : 2
Maximum value : 6
Minimum value : 1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can you please explain this part 
``#define MIN(a,b) (((a)<(b))?(a):(b))
#define MAX(a,b) (((a)>(b))?(a):(b))``
or give any links where I can learn about it.

Comment: ``int value_max=INT_MIN;
    int value_min=INT_MAX;``
what is the difference between initializing it to 9 and 0 or your way?
I tried both and get the same answer, just really curious

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void test(int N){
    int arr[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
    for (int i =0; i < N; i++){ 
        int num;
        printf ("Please enter the number in range from 0 to 9 (to break enter: 11): ");
        scanf ("%d",&num);
        if (num==11) break;
        if (num>9 || num<0){
            printf("Number is not in range 0..9! Try another number..\n");
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        arr[num]++;
    }

    int max = 0, min = 9, max_occurrences = 0, min_occurrences = N;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      printf ("Number %d occured %d times\n", i, arr[i]);
        max_occurrences = arr[max_occurrences] < arr[i] && arr[i]!=0? i : max_occurrences;
        min_occurrences = arr[min_occurrences] > arr[i] && arr[i]!=0? i : min_occurrences;
        max = max < i && arr[i]!=0? i : max;
        min = min > i && arr[i]!=0? i : min;


    }
    printf("max occurrences : %d \nmin occurrences : %d \nmax common : %d \nmin common : %d \n ", max_occurrences, min_occurrences, max, min);
}

int main()
{
  test(6);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have only doubts about `max =  0, min = 9, max_occurrences = 0, min_occurrences = 9;` - what if `N` is `100` and I input number `1` hundred times? Actually in your example `N` is `10` - what happens if I input the same number `10` times? I think you could just initialize with `N + 1`. Note to others that `scanf` needs here to be worked on - this code does not break at number  `11` entered, doesn't check if the value is within `0...9` range and doesn't check the return value of scanf. Och right, you can initialize to N. I think `min = N` too, right? or `max = N`, I am not sure.

Comment: @Kamil Cuk, yeap, you right) it mast be much bigger

Comment: @Kamil Cuk, thanks for advice, it's very helpful! I try this now

Comment: You can (should ?) display `printf ("Number %d occured %d times\n", i, arr[i]);` and calculate the min/max/min occurence/max occurence in the same loop.

Comment: @Cid , sure, i can, and i must did that, sorry for missing this!

Comment: This actually doesn't get the `max_occurrences` not the `min_occurence`. At the end of the loop, `max_occurrences` is equal to the last element of the array that is different of `0` and has index > 1. `min_occurence`  is equal to  is equal to the last element of the array that is different of `0`

Comment: If `N == 6` and I input `1`,  `1`, `1`, `2`, `9`, `9` , both values min and max with be equal to 9 when max_occurence should be 1 and min_occurence should be 2

Comment: `max_occurrences < i` evaluate to `false` on first iteration, since `0 < 0` is false

Comment: @Cid, I tested my code, and it work right.. I dont understand the problem.
With your input my res will be :
max occurrences : 9 
min occurrences : 1 
max common : 3 
min common : 0

Comment: max occurence should be 1 because 1 appears 3 times. Min occurence should be 2 because it appears only once. Max should be 9 (that's the max value) min should be 1

Comment: @Cid, sorry,i misunderstanded question, and print the number of occurence of max/min occurence instad index

Comment: `max_occurrences = max_occurrences < i && arr[i]!=0? i : max_occurrences;` Should this be `max_occurrences = arr[max_occurrences] < arr[i] && arr[i]!=0? i : max_occurrences;` ?

Comment: Thank you, but this one requires to specify the N number before continuing with getting input from the user right?

Comment: @Marietta No, but you can easy add scanf to N, or you can set a contestant value to N

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int min(int a, int b) { return (a < b) ? a : b; }
int max(int a, int b) { return (a > b) ? a : b; }
int valid(int n) { return (n >= 0 && n <= 9) ? 1 : 0; }

int main() {
    int i, n, min_number = 10, max_number = -1, max_frequency = 0;
    int freq[10] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    // Read all numbers from input (read until end of file or press Ctrl+Z in console)
    while (scanf("%d", &n) > 0) {
        if (valid(n) == 0) {
            printf("Number %d is invalid and will be ignored\n", n);
            continue;
        }
        freq[n] += 1;
        min_number = min(min_number, n);
        max_number = max(max_number, n);
        max_frequency = max(max_frequency, freq[n]);
    }

    printf("Occurences of digits:\n");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        printf("Number %d occured %d times\n", i, freq[i]);
    printf("\n\nMin value: %d\n", min);
    printf("Max value: %d\n", max);

    // Print numbers with greatest frequency
    printf("\n\nMost common numbers: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        if (freq[i] == max_frequency)
            printf("%d\n", i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```